# How to exit or continue in C#

Tags: c#

I was wondering if this is simple or complicated, how to exit or continue a small simple app.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter an integer: ");
int myInt = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
bool isLessThan10 = myInt < 10;
bool isBetween0And5 = (0 <= myInt) && (myInt <= 5);
Console.WriteLine("Integer less than 10? {0}", isLessThan10);
Console.WriteLine("Integer between 0 and 5? {0}", isBetween0And5);
Console.ReadKey();
```

How to make it ask a question saying Do you want to quit this or continue and Yes to continue and No to quit.

I don't know to do that, please help!

Thanks

Comment: Easiest to use Console.ReadLine() instead of ReadKey.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
do {

        //Your Code

        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue (Y/N)? "); 
    }while (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar != 'Y');
```

or

```
 do {

            //Your Code

            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue (Y/N)? "); 
        }while (Console.ReadLine() != "Y");
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are not looking for a GUI 'Input Box'( I assume you are doing a console-based application).
A simple console message with a keyInput will do.

```
    char key = 0;
    while( key != 'Q'){

        //Your Code
        //
        Console.WriteLine("Press Q to quit."); 
        key = Console.Readkey();
    }
```

You can replace the 'While' with 'do-while' as well'

Answer (score 0):

```
        Console.Write("Press any key to continue or 'n' to abort:");
        if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.N)
            return;
```